# Foreign key issues, error code 1452

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have bumped into an issue with my foreign key twice today, and for some i keep getting error code 1452, and dont know what to do:

```
CREATE TABLE `character_` (
  `Name_` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Class` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Homeworld` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rank` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Str` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Per` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Int_` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Agi` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Name_`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `world_type` (
  `Name_` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Skills` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bonus` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Penalty` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Name_`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

after i have done this i try to add the foeign key from Homeworld in character_ to Name_ in world_type and this is the message i get.

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dark_heresy`.`#sql-c20_2`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-c20_2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Homeworld`) REFERENCES `world_type` (`Name_`))
```

The same goes for this table, but its a bit different structured, the idea is that i has a compound key. in the requierment table:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Name_` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Weight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Value_` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Availability` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `talents` (
  `SkillName` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Bonus` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Str` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_WS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_BS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Fel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Per` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Int` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Agi` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_WP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Talent_requiert` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SkillName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `requierments` (
  `item_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SName` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_ID`,`SName`),
  CONSTRAINT `requierments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_ID`) REFERENCES `item` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As its shown in the requierments table the foreign key from item_ID to ID in item has been successful but, when i try to do:

```
ALTER TABLE requierments
ADD FOREIGN KEY (SName)
REFERENCES talents (SkillName);
```

the same error code i get:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dark_heresy`.`#sql-c20_2`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-c20_2_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`SName`) REFERENCES `talents` (`SkillName`))
```

please help i am starting to get desperate.

Thanks in advance

Data input:

```
INSERT INTO character_ ( Name_, Class, Homeworld, Rank, Str, WS, BS, Fel, Per, Int_, Agi, WP) VALUES (
'Atelus Flex', 'Psyker', 'Void', 'Sanctio nite', 30, 31, 29, 37, 31, 40, 32, 40);

INSERT INTO character_ ( Name_, Class, Homeworld, Rank, Str, WS, BS, Fel, Per, Int_, Agi, WP) VALUES (
'Varg Rexxar', 'Assassin', 'Feral', 'Sell steel', 37, 40, 36, 20, 37, 28, 41, 30);

INSERT INTO character_ ( Name_, Class, Homeworld, Rank, Str, WS, BS, Fel, Per, Int_, Agi, WP) VALUES (
'Marr', 'Adept', 'Void', 'Archivist', 32, 34, 42, 20, 51, 31, 24, 33);

INSERT INTO character_ ( Name_, Class, Homeworld, Rank, Str, WS, BS, Fel, Per, Int_, Agi, WP) VALUES (
'Morrison', 'Tech Priest', 'Void', 'Technographer', 25, 30, 40, 33, 24, 34, 31, 32 );

INSERT INTO character_ ( Name_, Class, Homeworld, Rank, Str, WS, BS, Fel, Per, Int_, Agi, WP) VALUES (
'Krohn', 'Scum', 'Feral', 'Dreg', 24, 32, 28, 34, 24, 28, 39, 32 );

INSERT INTO World_type ( Name_, skills, bonus, penalty, Description) VALUES (
'Feral World', 'Tribal Dialect', 'Iron Stomach', 'Primitive', 'Feral Worlders are big, strong and tough');

INSERT INTO World_type ( Name_, skills, bonus, penalty, Description) VALUES (
'Hive World', 'accustomed to crowds', 'caves of steel', 'Hivebound', 'Hivers are fast talking, quick thinking individuals' );

INSERT INTO World_type ( Name_, skills, bonus, penalty, Description) VALUES (
'Imperial World', 'Hagiography', 'superior origins', 'blessed ignorance', 'Imperial citizens comes from all sorts of different planets and cultures' );

INSERT INTO World_type ( Name_, skills, bonus, penalty, Description) VALUES (
'Void Born', 'shipwise', 'charmed', 'ill omened', 'Void born are weirdly lucky and strong willed' );


INSERT INTO Item ( ID, Name_, Weight, Value_, Availability) VALUES (
01, 'Las Carbine', 3, 75, 'Common' );

INSERT INTO Item ( ID, Name_, Weight, Value_, Availability) VALUES (
02, 'Laspistol', 1, 50, 'Common' );

INSERT INTO Item ( ID, Name_, Weight, Value_, Availability) VALUES (
03, 'Shotgun', 5, 60, 'average' );

INSERT INTO Item ( ID, Name_, Weight, Value_, Availability) VALUES (
04, 'Heavy Bolter', 40, 2000, 'Very Rare' );

INSERT INTO Item ( ID, Name_, Weight, Value_, Availability) VALUES (
05, 'Needle pistol', 2, 1250, 'Very Rare' );

INSERT INTO Item ( ID, Name_, Weight, Value_, Availability) VALUES (
06, 'Chainsword', 6, 275, 'Rare' );

INSERT INTO Item ( ID, Name_, Weight, Value_, Availability) VALUES (
07, 'Power Sword', 4, 2500, 'Very Rare' );


INSERT INTO Talents ( SkillName, Bonus, Description, R_Str, R_WS, R_BS, R_Fel, R_Per, R_Int, R_Agi, R_WP, Talent_requiert) VALUES (
 'ambidextrous', 0, 'use either hand equally well', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, null);

INSERT INTO Talents ( SkillName, Bonus, Description, R_Str, R_WS, R_BS, R_Fel, R_Per, R_Int, R_Agi, R_WP, Talent_requiert) VALUES (
 'Frenzy', 0, 'enter psychotic rage to gain combat bonus', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);

INSERT INTO Talents ( SkillName, Bonus, Description, R_Str, R_WS, R_BS, R_Fel, R_Per, R_Int, R_Agi, R_WP, Talent_requiert) VALUES (
 'battle rage', 0, 'parry while frenzied', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Frenzy');

INSERT INTO Talents ( SkillName, Bonus, Description, R_Str, R_WS, R_BS, R_Fel, R_Per, R_Int, R_Agi, R_WP, Talent_requiert) VALUES (
 'Exotic Weapons', 0, 'Player is able to use exotic weapons', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Basic weapons');

INSERT INTO Talents ( SkillName, Bonus, Description, R_Str, R_WS, R_BS, R_Fel, R_Per, R_Int, R_Agi, R_WP, Talent_requiert) VALUES (
 'Basic weapons', 0, 'Player is able to use Basic weapons', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);

INSERT INTO Talents ( SkillName, Bonus, Description, R_Str, R_WS, R_BS, R_Fel, R_Per, R_Int, R_Agi, R_WP, Talent_requiert) VALUES (
 'Heavy weapon', 0, 'Player is able to use heavy weapons', 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);

INSERT INTO Talents ( SkillName, Bonus, Description, R_Str, R_WS, R_BS, R_Fel, R_Per, R_Int, R_Agi, R_WP, Talent_requiert) VALUES (
 'Power weapon', 0, 'Player is able to use power weapons ', 40, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);


INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
01, 'Basic weapons');

INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
02, null);

INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
03, null);

INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
04, 'Heavy weapon');

INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
05, 'Exotic Weapons');

INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
06, 'Heavy weapon');

INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
07, 'Power weapon');


INSERT INTO learned (CName, SName) VALUES (
'Varg Rexxar','ambidextrous' ); 

INSERT INTO learned (CName, SName) VALUES (
'Krohn','Frenzy');

INSERT INTO learned (CName, SName) VALUES (
'Marr','Basic weapons');

INSERT INTO learned (CName, SName) VALUES (
'Atelus Flex','Basic weapons');

INSERT INTO learned (CName, SName) VALUES (
'Morrison','Basic weapons');
```

Comment: I can't replicate your error. Do you have data in the tables when you try to add this foreign keys? If you have something in requierments.sname that doesn't exist in talents.skillName you should get that error.

Comment: @FilipeSilva i have edited the post so you can see the data, i have inputted, and i have changed the values, so they match in foreign key and primary key

Comment: I'm guessing he does, a character with a Homeworld = dark_heresy but no matching entry in the world_type table.

Comment: @Santelices. Were you able to make it work?

Comment: Nope @FilipeSilva still having issues with it. i have tried now to enter ID in the world_type, and now tells me the error 1215 i guess it is becuase they dont have the same value (one is int and the other i varchar) and the idea is not to have the Homeworld in character_ with numbers, but with names. you typed before "There was one character_ in there with Homeworld = Archivist that does not exist in your world_type list." but as far i can see is Archivist a Rank in the tablet.

Comment: also @FilipeSilva i saw that i posted INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
02, null);

INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
03, null); but notest that it was the earlier code, becuase the one i the database i where the null is changed to '' instead of null, since it is not allowed to null

Answer (score 0):

The first part:
By adding a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE character_
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Homeworld)
REFERENCES world_type (Name_);
```

You are telling the table character_ that the values in HomeWorld will always be present in world_type.Name_.

But you are trying to insert them in character_ before inserting them in world_type. This would give an error right away.

Changing order, it still gives error because you are using only parts of the world_type.name_ in Homeworld. You should probably use a ID for this instead. Put an ID in world_type and then reference it in Character.

If not, you should do:

```
INSERT INTO World_type ( Name_, skills, bonus, penalty, Description) VALUES (
'Feral World', 'Tribal Dialect', 'Iron Stomach', 'Primitive', 'Feral Worlders are big, strong and tough');

INSERT INTO World_type ( Name_, skills, bonus, penalty, Description) VALUES (
'Hive World', 'accustomed to crowds', 'caves of steel', 'Hivebound', 'Hivers are fast talking, quick thinking individuals' );

INSERT INTO World_type ( Name_, skills, bonus, penalty, Description) VALUES (
'Imperial World', 'Hagiography', 'superior origins', 'blessed ignorance', 'Imperial citizens comes from all sorts of different planets and cultures' );

INSERT INTO World_type ( Name_, skills, bonus, penalty, Description) VALUES (
'Void Born', 'shipwise', 'charmed', 'ill omened', 'Void born are weirdly lucky and strong willed' );


INSERT INTO character_ ( Name_, Class, Homeworld, Rank, Str, WS, BS, Fel, Per, Int_, Agi, WP) VALUES (
'Atelus Flex', 'Psyker', 'Void Born', 'Sanctio nite', 30, 31, 29, 37, 31, 40, 32, 40);

INSERT INTO character_ ( Name_, Class, Homeworld, Rank, Str, WS, BS, Fel, Per, Int_, Agi, WP) VALUES (
'Varg Rexxar', 'Assassin', 'Feral World', 'Sell steel', 37, 40, 36, 20, 37, 28, 41, 30);


INSERT INTO character_ ( Name_, Class, Homeworld, Rank, Str, WS, BS, Fel, Per, Int_, Agi, WP) VALUES (
'Morrison', 'Tech Priest', 'Void Born', 'Technographer', 25, 30, 40, 33, 24, 34, 31, 32 );

INSERT INTO character_ ( Name_, Class, Homeworld, Rank, Str, WS, BS, Fel, Per, Int_, Agi, WP) VALUES (
'Krohn', 'Scum', 'Feral World', 'Dreg', 24, 32, 28, 34, 24, 28, 39, 32 );
```

There was one character_ in there with Homeworld = `Archivist` that does not exist in your world_type list.

Then below you had:

You say in table requierments:

```
`SName` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

But then you do:

```
INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
02, null);

INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
03, null);
```

This can't happen either.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71b42)</kbd>

This is not a final result. You have to put the world_types and Snames correctly, but it is creating and inserting without errors.